# How can I replace a JavaFX GridPane with another one? I try and I get a duplication error

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, children

Let's say I have two of the GridPane and a menu bar up top

```
// buttons
buttonLaunchOne = new Button("one");
buttonLaunchTwo = new Button("two")

// menu
GridPane menuLayout = new GridPane();
menuLayout.setMinSize(500, 500 );
menuLayout.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
menuLayout.add(buttonLaunchOne, 0, 0);
menuLayout.add(buttonLaunchTwo, 2, 0);

// one
GridPane twoLayout = new GridPane();
resultsLayout.add(buttonOne, 1, 1);

// two
GridPane oneLayout = new GridPane();
profileLayout.add(buttonTwo, 0, 1);
```

Then I have two action events

```
buttonLaunchOne.setOnAction(e -> {
    menuLayout.add(firstLayout, 0, 1);
    mainWindow.setTitle("Admin Portal: One");
});
buttonLaunchTwo.setOnAction(e -> {
     menuLayout.add(secondLayout, 0, 1);
     mainWindow.setTitle("Admin Portal: Two");
});
```

here is the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_CENTER
                                    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
                                    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.add(GridPane.java:965)
                                    at sample.Main.lambda$start$1(Main.java:67)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
                                    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
                                    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
                                    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
                                    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
                                    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
                                    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
                                    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
                                    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
                                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
                                    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
                                    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
                                    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
                                    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
                                    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried this with a remove statement before adding the layouts and still get the error.
I just want to replace where one layout is with another one when a button is clicked.
I am not sure if what I want to do is really even possible, I just need insight. Thank you and if you need more of the code I have just ask, and I will do so! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. The code snippets you posted refer to several elements whose code you've not included. Also, post the exact error messages you're getting.

Comment: I have already added the error code, I edited it before I saw this comment. My bad. This is the only thing that has anything to do with what I need. I will try and add more.

Comment: did you try getchildren().clear instead of remove?